# confusion about Ruby regular expression to match valid String

Tags: ruby, regex

Suppose I hvae a match pattern in Ruby regular expression:

```
VALID_ID = /^[-a-z0-9_.]+$/i
```

I think it matchs all strings that with characters `-`, `_`, `0-9`, 'a-z', 'A-Z'. But, I feel confused about the last character `.` here. What does it mean? Can you provide some examples to explain it?

Comment: `.` is a character literal here.. To match a name like `arup11.rakshit`,`arup.rakshit` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the dot(`.`) outside the `[]` then it means any character except `\n`. But if you place this dot(`.`) inside the `[]`(also known as character-class), then it means only to match the dot(`.`)

For example:

`/[.]/` will match with `.`

and  `/./` will match with any characters excepts `\n`

Answer (score 2):

It matches the char `.`, the `.` inside `[]` is just the dot char, doesn't have a special meaning.